# jCarousel issue - Hover images opacity settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

So far I have got jCarousel to display, and load the images via a txt file,

What I want to do is show 4 images at a time, then when the user puts the mouse over 1 of the images the other 3 images to fade opacity, to 30%. Then if they move the mouse to the image next to it I want that image to be 100% opacity and the other 3 images 30% opacity.

So the image with the mouse over it will always be 100% opacity, and the others 30%, so it stands out. When the user moves the mouse out of the jCarousel box I want all images to show 100% opacity.

I'm using code similar to this

Thanks.

**Edit**

**Sorry I should have added code before, here it is: http://pastebin.com/m54cd73d8
This is what I have so far nickrance.co.uk/jcarousel/dynamic_ajax.html
It kind of works, it fades the inactive images, but I think it needs a mouseout event to restore the opacity of all images when the mouse moves out of the jCarousel div.
Also, it seems to be only working for the first 4 images, and I have 10 images in the carousel, the others don't seem to do anything :s**

**New Current code:**
So far

```
 
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    var activeOpacity   = 1.0,
        inactiveOpacity = 0.3,
        testOpacity = 0.3,
        fadeTime = 50,
        clickedClass = "selected",
        thumbs = "#mycarousel li";

  $(thumbs).fadeTo(1.0, activeOpacity);

    $(thumbs).hover(
        function(){

            $(thumbs).fadeTo(fadeTime, inactiveOpacity);

          $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
        },
        function(){
            // Only fade out if the user hasn't clicked the thumb
            if(!$(this).hasClass(clickedClass)) {
                $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
            }
        });
     $(thumbs).click(function() {
         // Remove selected class from any elements other than this
         var previous = $(thumbs + '.' + clickedClass).eq();
         var clicked = $(this);
         if(clicked !== previous) {
             previous.removeClass(clickedClass);
         }
         clicked.addClass(clickedClass).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
     });
});
```

Comment: We need to see your exact code. Post it or don't expect an answer that will fix your problem.

Comment: Code added - http://pastebin.com/m54cd73d8

Sorry should have added it before!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to yours and you will be fine:

```
$(".jcarousel-wrapper").on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(thumbs).fadeTo(fadeTime, 1.0);
});
```

And your HTML must be something like this:

```
<div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
   <div class="jcarousel">
       <ul id="mycarousel">
            <li>...
```

Then all images will fade opacity to 1 when mouse leave your carousel...